# jQuery load on Scroll - fade in table rows as scroll to display block. Endless scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

Is this possible without no PHP, SQL, .NET etc, just need jQuery, HMTL and CSS.

I have a table and rather than having pagination I want to be able to load in other rows as I scroll down the page, similar to that of Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: Yes it's possible with ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Quote from plugin page : 
"you don’t need to code any custom backend stuff to enable this functionality!"